# Parsing XML leads to System.Xml.XmlException: Element 'Customer' was not found

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Here is my code and it keeps throwing exception that System.Xml.XmlException: Element 'Customer' was not found.And XML file pasted at bottom

```
public static List<Customer> GetCustomers()
{
    // create the list
    List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();

    // create the XmlReaderSettings object
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
    settings.IgnoreComments = true;

    // create the XmlReader object
    XmlReader xmlIn = XmlReader.Create(path, settings);

    // read past all nodes to the first Customer node
    xmlIn.ReadToDescendant("Customers");

    // create one Customer object for each Customer node
    do
    {
        Customer c = new Customer();
        xmlIn.ReadStartElement("Customer");
        c.FirstName =
            xmlIn.ReadElementContentAsString();
        c.LastName =
            xmlIn.ReadElementContentAsString();
        c.Email =
            xmlIn.ReadElementContentAsString();
        customers.Add(c);
    }
    while (xmlIn.ReadToNextSibling("Customer"));

    // close the XmlReader object
    xmlIn.Close();

    return customers;
```

Here is my XML and it clearly contains Element Customer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Customers>
    <Customer>
        <FirstName>John</FirstName>
        <LastName>Smith</LastName>
        <Email>jsmith@gmail.com</Email>
    </Customer>
    <Customer>
        <FirstName>Jane</FirstName>
        <LastName>Doe</LastName>
        <Email>janedoe@yahoo.com</Email>
    </Customer>
</Customers>
```

Answer (score 2):

From the docs for [`ReadStartElement(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7e4769a.aspx):

> Checks that the current content node is an element with the given Name and advances the reader to the next node.

When you've only called `ReadToDescendant("Customers")` the current node will be `Customers`, not `Customer`.

You *can* fix this either by changing that to `ReadToDescendants("Customer")` or by adding an extra call like that after the first one.

Do you really *need* to use `XmlReader` though? If you could read it using LINQ to XML your code would be *much* simpler:

```
return XDocument.Load(path)
                .Root
                .Elements("Customer")
                .Select(x => new Customer {
                           FirstName = (string) x.Element("FirstName"),
                           LastName = (string) x.Element("LastName"),
                           Email = (string) x.Element("Email")
                        })
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks!Finally got it,I was so frustrated by it.I really need to learn LINQ.You are author of C# in depth?I read your book but it was too advanced for me.

Comment: @user1125033: Yup, that's my book. Hopefully you'll find it more useful when you've got a bit more experience. And yes, you *really* should learn LINQ. It's great :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ReadToDescendent, I think you need to read until the "Customer" node, like so:

```
// read past all nodes to the first Customer node
xmlIn.ReadToDescendant("Customer");
```